# Return parent row then child rows in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, hierarchical

I'm trying to return data from `family` in the following structure:

- Parent A row
- A's child 1 row
- A's child 2 row
- A's child 3 row
- Parent B row
- B's child 1 row
- B's child 2 row
- B's child 3 row

`Family` returns parent and child data all together, like:

- 1 parent A columns, A's child 1 columns
- 2 parents A columns, A's child 2 columns
- 3 parents A columns, A's child 3 columns

My attempts so far with `connect by prior` results in the error:

> ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data

I suspect, but I'm not certain, that should be using `connect by level` instead, but each of my attempts with that fails.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my desired format?

```
with parents
as (
    select *
    from view_sot sot
    where sot.tree = 'parent'
        and sot.xmode = 'E'
    ),
children
as (
    select *
    from view_sot sot
    where sot.tree = 'child'
        and sot.xmode != 'E'
    ),
family
as (
    select parents.srn psrn,
        parents.cand pcand,
        parents.ayrc payrc,
        parents.mod_code pmod_code,
        parents.mark pmark,
        parents.grade pgrade,
        parents.xmode pxmode,
        parents.mavo pmavo,
        parents.mod_name pmod_name,
        parents.prg_code pprg_code,
        parents.tree ptree,
        children.srn csrn,
        children.cand ccand,
        children.ayrc cayrc,
        children.mod_code cmod_code,
        children.mark cmark,
        children.grade cgrade,
        children.xmode cxmode,
        children.mavo cmavo,
        children.mod_name cmod_name,
        children.prg_code cprg_code,
        children.tree ctree
    from parents
    inner join children on parents.srn = children.srn
        and parents.mod_code = children.mod_code
        and parents.ayrc = children.ayrc
        and parents.cand = children.cand
        and parents.mavo = children.mavo
    where parents.srn = 'A012345678'
    )
select psrn,
    pxmode,
    pmod_code,
    cmod_code,
    cxmode,
    level
from family connect by prior cmod_code = pmod_code
```

Many thanks

Comment: No clue what all those columns mean.... You should better give the table structure and the meaning of each of the relevant columns. Leave out fields which are not relevant to your question (also from your SQL).

Comment: Post a small reproducible test case and you're more likely to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any context or data in your question, I just built a silly example - is this what you want?

```
with family as
  (select 1 as id_num, 'Jay-Z' as the_name, 'parent' as who, 2 as family, 0 as parent_id from dual
    union all
   select 2 as id_num, 'Beyonce' as the_name, 'parent' as who, 2 as family,     0 as parent_id from dual
     union all
   select 11 as id_num, 'Blue Ivy' as the_name, 'child' as who, 2 as family,     1 as parent_id from dual
      union all
   select 11 as id_num, 'Blue Ivy' as the_name, 'child' as who, 2 as family,     2 as parent_id from dual
   union all
    select 22 as id_num, 'Upcoming Twin #1' as the_name, 'child' as who, 2     as family, 1 as parent_id from dual
   union all
    select 22 as id_num, 'Upcoming Twin #1' as the_name, 'child' as who, 2     as family, 2 as parent_id from dual
       union all
     select 33 as id_num, 'Upcoming Twin #2' as the_name, 'child' as who, 2     as family, 1 as parent_id from dual
   union all
    select 33 as id_num, 'Upcoming Twin #2' as the_name, 'child' as who, 2     as family, 2 as parent_id from dual)

select lpad('.',level*3-3,'.')||the_name
from family
where ((level = 1 and who = 'parent') or (level = 2))
connect by prior id_num = parent_id
order siblings by the_name;   



OUTPUT >>>>
Beyonce
...Blue Ivy
...Upcoming Twin #1
...Upcoming Twin #2
Jay-Z
...Blue Ivy
...Upcoming Twin #1
...Upcoming Twin #2
```

I'm unclear as to if you have multiple rows per child (one row per child per parent).... but hopefully this syntax will at least guide you.

Comment: Thanks so much for this @fleetmack. This gives me the start I need. Also, my apologies for the late reply -- I work part-time.

Comment: .@fleetmack how would I exclude the children listed at the bottom of your example, so that just the first eight rows were returned?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. You'd need to do some comparison on the level to pull this off, not knowing your data I can't say for sure, but I just edited my code to include a where clause which accomplishes what you're trying to do .... check that out and play around a bit.